# Music (genres) recognition using c#

Tags: c#, .net, sound-recognition

I need to do a music recognition application in C# for school purposes (recognition of some music genres - styles)

Can you recommend some GOOD way (sources, APIs, libraries, articles) to do this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Recognition of genre is *very* subjective - you might need to narrow down that requirement somewhat before it becomes feasible!

Comment: I think the proper way here is to ask a similar question, sans programming language part, on a mathematical or data processing site instead. If you can mathematically model how to detect music genres, I'd assume a program to do it would be short work. I suspect, however, that the algorithmic part here is going to kill this project.

Answer (score 0):

> The Fourier Transform for the music
>   has been explored over and over and
>   nothing useful could be found. It is
>   just given that it is not really
>   helpful. DirectSound is also not the
>   way to go.
>
> I posted this post before the switch
>   to the new format but apparently it
>   was lost although I saw it clearly
>   posted. It is an afterthought to what
>   I've said before. What I said was that
>   it is unclear how far the OP wants to
>   go: if he wants to do some research to
>   break a new ground or simply find C#
>   code for established conceptual
>   frameworks? If he is not averse to
>   research then there was an article in
>   Nature or Science recently whereby
>   they laid out a framework for a
>   mathematical description of human
>   music perception. The whole idea is
>   that the musical notes fall into a
>   network of nodes which can be
>   stretched over a lattice kind of like
>   the Mobius surface but more
>   complicated. It is a multidimensiona
>   space. The distances (metric) are
>   defined pretty much like musician do
>   it. You have to do the Fourier of
>   course to take the atoms of music.
>   Thus my speculation is that if the OP
>   takes an arbitrary recording, does
>   frequency analysis and places the
>   sounds onto a lattice like that and
>   all sounds fit then he can say that it
>   is music. If they fall in between and
>   the representation becomes blurry then
>   it is noise.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/7dc276d7-2b05-4677-8fd0-5eb3c9a170a7)